# time between applyingchanges event fire and changesapplied event fire

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I am building an occasionaly connected application using SyncFramework. SQL Server is used in the server-side, SQLCE 3.5 as client-side. As sync providers I'm using DbServerSyncProvider in the server-side and SqlCeClientSyncProvider in the client-side.

Trying to fix some performance issues, I realized that even in case that there are not changes to be applyied in the client, there is a considerable amount of time between applyingchanges - changesapplyied, even if there is no changes to be applied.

Follows some data about these times:

1. TabelasDeConfiguracaoGroup - SelectingChanges:  SERV
2. TabelasDeConfiguracaoGroup - ChangesSelected  SERV  00:00:00,0
3. TabelasDeConfiguracaoGroup - ApplyingChanges: 0 changes -  CLIENT   00:00:00,1
4. TabelasDeConfiguracaoGroup - ChangesApplied: 0 changes -  CLIENT    00:00:01,1

Interpretation: time between event 1 and 2 is 00:00:00,0 - time between event 2 and 3 00:00:00,1...

As we can see, applying changes is the most wasting operation, even if we don't have any changes to be applyied.

Someone knows why so much time? Is it normal? Is there some way to improve it?
Maybe 1 seconds is not much but I am afraid it will increases as the number of tables increases.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which sync provider are you using?

Comment: In the client-side I'm using SqlCeClientSyncProvider and in the server-side I'm using DbServerSyncProvider.

Comment: that must be the time spent updating the send/receive anchor per table...